# MySQL SELECT whole oldest day from DATETIME

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

please help me :-) This is absolutely new for me and i have no idea how to do this.

I have MySQL table with this structure and these values:

| material_id (INT) | material_referenceid (INT) | material_cas (DATETIME) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 13 | 2021-11-01T17:19:08Z |
| 10 | 13 | 2021-11-08T17:19:28Z |
| 23 | 24 | 2021-11-04T17:41:48Z |
| 25 | 4 | 2021-11-02T17:40:51Z |
| 27 | 13 | 2021-11-01T17:19:19Z |
| 30 | 24 | 2021-10-11T17:41:31Z |
| 33 | 24 | 2021-10-11T17:41:41Z |

I need to display all rows where material_referenceid = (for example) 13 and date = WHOLE OLDEST DAY value in table. So from this table i would like to get rows with material_id = 2, 27. When these two deleted, will select 10.

Many thanks in advance for everybody who will help me with this. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: oldest day in UTC?  or some other timezone?

Comment: please don't keep your table name a secret; it makes it harder to answer your question

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Table name is, for example, "material". Timezone is Europe/Prague.

Comment: are your material_cas values in Europe/Prague?  the Z makes me think you are storing them as UTC (which you should!), but that's something whatever client you are using is adding

Comment: Another mistake, i will use TIMESTAMP instead DATETIME.

Comment: there's not a lot of difference between the two, both have some quirks.  changing from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP doesn't make any difference here.  you are still either storing them in UTC or in some other timezone

Comment: Storing will be automatic by column type by NOW() function.

Comment: if you are using NOW(), then it will store as whatever the server or session timezone is set to.  I recommend never using NOW or CURDATE/CURRENT_DATE when inserting/updating and always using UTC_TIMESTAMP() to store as UTC

Comment: OK, thanks for advice.

Comment: I'm not clear in what you are trying to achieve, do you want a select to get three rows with material_id equal to 2, 10, 27 and material_cas 2021-11-01T17:19:08Z because is the older of ALL rows whatever the value of Material_referenceid or because it's the older value of the rows with material_referenceid equal to 13?

Comment: I'm making very simple warehouse storage management with FIFO control. material_referenceid is material number and material_id is exact pallet with this material. material_cas is time of storage of this material/pallet. If I search for some material number, i would like to get not only one oldest pallet, but all in oldest day of storage time. So from this table, if i search for material_referenceid = 13, i will get material_id = 2,27 (because they are same oldest day). If i delete this rows (removed from storage), i get 10. Sorry for my english, hope I have explained it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to select the oldest day (in a subquery) and join that back to the table.

To select the oldest day:

```
select date(min(material_cas)) from material where material_referenceid = 13
```

So, using that:

```
select m.material_id, m.material_cas
from (
   select date(min(material_cas)) oldest_date from material where material_referenceid = 13
) oldest
join material m on m.material_reference_id=13 and date(m.material_cas)=oldest_date
```

Assuming material_cas is stored in UTC, to look based on the Europe/Prague date, do instead:

```
select m.material_id, m.material_cas
from (
   select date(convert_tz(min(material_cas),'+00:00','Europe/Prague')) oldest_date from material where material_referenceid = 13
) oldest
join material m on m.material_reference_id=13 and date(convert_tz(m.material_cas,'+00:00','Europe/Prague'))=oldest_date
```